# Error installing mysql workbench on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

Mysql workbench worked properly on my ubuntu 1404 but after I installed python 2.7, mysql workbench cannot connect because 'ssh tunnel manager'. Then I uninstalled mysql workbench in order to reinstall it but when I reinstalled mysql workbench i got the following error

```
mysql-workbench-community depends on libctemplate2; however:
Package libctemplate2 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7); however:
Package libpcrecpp0:amd64 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...  
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-workbench-community
```

I already update all of package but nothing changed. Any suggestion ?

Comment: try: apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps mentioned in the below link.I couldn't able to manually resolve the dependencies after getting the dependency error.I have tried the below solution and it worked for me.Good solution.

http://bgasparotto.com/install-mysql-workbench-ubuntu/